# Custom HTML in Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, plugins

I'm currently working on a Wordpress website.

I'm not a massively proficient coder and I'm trying to find a way to list selected options in the configurator price section?

I thought I may be able to do this with some custom HTML.

Is this possible or will it need to be completely custom coded?

Any ideas would be massively helpful.

Here's the current state of the page - https://gof.co.uk/test-configurator/

Here's what I'm hoping it can look like

[Link to website screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ColiO.jpg)

Comment: can you share screenshot for what you expect?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've added an image link of what I'm hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would require some custom javascript but wouldn't be extremely difficult.

The selected option gets "current" added to it. This could be used to pull the data-text value to add the options at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mark. Where is a good place to start to find javascript that I may need? I have no experience of javascript at all.